# Rotational motion and angular momentum ABOUT centre of mass

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

Note- By COM i mean the Centre of mass.
What i have been thaught about the net angular momentum of a system is that -
$$\vec{L}_{Net}=\vec{L}_{ of COM}+\vec{L}_{About COM}$$
Now here the $$\vec{L}_{ of COM}$$ is simple enough to calculate in most cases because COM is a point and so we need to consider only a translatory frame of reference
But the $$\vec{L}_{About COM}$$ doesnt seem to only include spin angular momentum but also the rotational effects too ( though i am not very clear why that is true)
So consider the following situation

[image: source- JEE adv 2016 Physics]

I am having a problem imagining how the situation would be in COM's frame of reference
My guess is that both $$\omega _{s}$$ and $$\omega _{o}$$ would exist but again i am unable to reason it
Also How will the discs move (in frame of COM) ? Imean will they revolve (like planets somewhat ) about COM ? and if they do so ,  about which axis will they revolve ?
I am trying to find the angular momentum about COM through this

[image: Relative frame of COM]

Comment: note - The source of this query is a  problem from JEE advance 2016